# Office 365 outlook "The set of folders cannot be opened" for shared calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar, microsoft

I have been having issues with shared calendars on my O365 Outlook desktop app. When I try to open a shared calendar I get "The set of folders cannot be opened" , my coworker who I share the calendars with has no issues at all.

I am running a Win 10 Enterprise box with 365 apps for enterprise. I've tried a few Band-Aid fixes that work for a little bit but then this issue comes up again

Fixes I've used:

1. create a new outlook profile
2. Open outlook in the 365 web browser, open the calendars, then open my outlook desktop app
3. Update Outlook

Let me know what you guys think!

Comment: Two tries: (1) Run once Outlook as Admin, (2) Check if it works when you [Open Outlook in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-outlook-in-safe-mode-f394c2ee-b2af-e97a-64ee-35cd24414811).

Comment: @harrymc So when I try opening as an admin it wants to add my admin account as a separate email, which it isn't associated with an email. Opening in safe mode worked, however if I open Outlook normally it still doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

As opening Outlook in safe mode worked, the problem is with some installed
extension.

Open Outlook menu *File > Options > Add-ins*, next to
"Manage: COM Add—ins" click "Go...".

Uncheck the add-ons selectively, click OK, restart Outlook and test.

Once you find the bad add-on, either use the Remove button to delete it,
or search for a newer and better version of it.

Comment: Okay, I unchecked an active client add-in (didn't remove it) and it seems to be working for now, I will follow up to see if that actually fixed it

Answer (score 0):

According to you description, I noticed that you have tried to start Outlook in safe mode and the issue didn't occur. Agree with @harrymc, you can try to [disable all the add ins and check which add ins cause it one by one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-can-t-start-microsoft-outlook-or-receive-the-error-cannot-start-microsoft-office-outlook-cannot-open-the-outlook-window-d1f69da6-b333-4650-97bf-4d77bd7abb85?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:%7E:text=Start%20Outlook%20in%20safe%20mode%20and%20disable%20add%2Dins).

If it doesn't work, as I know,  Outlook has disabled some features other than add ins that may cause problems in safe mode. In addition to disabling the add-on, we can also use the following methods for troubleshooting:

1.Clear and regenerate the navigation pane of the current profile through **Win+R > Outlook.exe /resetnavpane** (note that there is a space between "Outlook. exe" and "/"):

[image]

2.If the problem is caused by an error in the custom toolbar, you can try to solve it by **resetting the toolbar** via **File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Export all customizations first to back up > Click Reset above Export option.**

[image]

3.**Reset all settings of Outlook under the registry**:

(Note: Serious problems can occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before making changes, [**back up the registry**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) to restore it in case something goes wrong.)

First enter **Win+R** to open Run window, and type Regedit to open Registry Editor:

[image]

Then navigate to **Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook**:

[image]

**Rename** the "Outlook" folder to "Outlook-1" and **restart your outlook client** to see if the problem is resolved.

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.